# how to create a token and then after access the action method in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postman

how to create a token in postman and then after authorize person access that actionresult index method in asp.net mvc

now when **I click on the send button of postman then direct access the index method that is issue I want to generate a token and then after authorize person access that method**

[image]

staticvariable.cs

```
   public static class staticvariable
    {
        public static HttpClient webapiclient = new HttpClient();

        static staticvariable()
        {
            webapiclient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5718/api/");
            webapiclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            webapiclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
    }
```

studController.cs

```
    public class studController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public JsonResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<student> studlist;
            HttpResponseMessage response = staticvariable.webapiclient.GetAsync("stud").Result;
            studlist = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<student>>().Result;
            return Json(studlist,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

when click the send button of the postman and then access the index method that is issue

what i want to

**when click on the send button of the postman then after generate the token means authoriz person can access that method**

Comment: how are you generating token?

Answer (score 0):

In Postman send an Http Post Request

Url :  http://localhost:5718/token

in form-data send 3  Key -> values

```
grant_type:password  // the word "password"
username:YOUR_USERNAME
password:YOUR_PASSWORD
```

then send the request

you will get a response with your Token

Comment: but issue is ```http://localhost:5718/token```         what token write after the 5718/token      that is the main issue?

Comment: not get the token in postman? please can you help more still I am finding the how to solve this issue?

Comment: you must already have username and password , then you send them in an Http Post request to "/token" to get your token for that user.

Comment: yes I have username and password but I have not idea how to send request still issue not solved this task is still pending I am not able to solve this task thanks for your suggestion and help